# Refresh Vaadin TabSheet upon maximizing Window

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin, vaadin7

I am having problem with Vaadin TabSheet - current tab doesn't resize upon maximizing/minimizing window (using the +/- button in top right corner)

My contents now **DO** resize correcty when:

- resizing/dragging the window using mouse
- switching to other tab
- **prior** to minimizing the window (they resize to fill 100% and then DON'T resize after the window is shrinked with "-" button, so they overflow to right)

But they **DON'T** resize at all when changing the state of the window (maximizing it or going back to original size (which is set to 800*600px))

I was able to isolate the window mode change event using `Window.WindowModeChangeListener`, but I cant figure out which method and upon which component shall I use to force the UI to repaint my tab...tried `markAsDirty` and `markAsDirtyRecursive` to everything (window, tabsheet, tabs themselves), but no luck...

Also window, tabsheet and tabs have `setImmediate(true)` if this shall be a concern. Or is there any other setting to ensure desired behaviour?

**EDIT:** I have noticed it even works right in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox (havent tried other browsers yet).

Comment: Please post some code, ideally a SSCCE.

Comment: When the resize works when you resize the browser window, but not when you maximize it, then it sounds like a bug in vaadin to me

Comment: cant really post company code here, nor I want trying to determine which part is "harmless" to post public...i tried to describe my situation as detailed as possible...

Comment: regarding the bug - it might be so, because I have noticed it works correctly in IE (but not in FF, which I use as default)

Comment: If you are using Valo, try the latest 7.7-SNAPSHOT. Sounds like a bug recently fixed

Comment: I doubt our project can just move to alpha prerelease, but I will have your suggestion in mind once 7.7 comes out as stable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug of Vaadin 7.6 and lower...